# How to check if newly cloned node is last node now in javascript

Tags: javascript, clone

I am trying to clone the last row in a table. So when the last row is cloned, the new row obviously becomes the last node. How do I made it that when that is clicked, it, itself creates a new node

```
window.onload = function() {

    var table = document.getElementById("nodeTable");
    var lastRow = table.rows[ table.rows.length - 1 ];

    lastRow.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var clone = lastRow.cloneNode(true);
        // var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        table.appendChild(clone);
        // now set the newly cloned node as the last node
        lastRow = table.rows[ table.rows.length - 1 ];
    });
```

It seems to want to just leave it at the previous node. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Delegate the event-listening to the `<table>`, or `<tbody>`, elements and work out from there if the clicked `<tr>` is currently the last-row of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following, listening for click-events at the level of the ancestor `<table>` and working out what element fired the event:

```
var table = document.getElementById('nodeTable');

// binding the event-listener to the <table>:
table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // this is the <table> itself,
  // this.rows is the collection of <tr> descendants:
  var rows = this.rows,
  // e.target is the clicked element:
    current = e.target,
    body = document.body,
  // getting the last row of the table:
    lastRow = rows[rows.length - 1];

  // while the clicked element does not have the (lower-cased) tagName of 'tr',
  // and it's not the 'body' (just for safety):
  while (current.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'tr' && current !== body) {
    // we update current to be its own parentNode and go again
    current = current.parentNode;
  }

  // if the current-element is the lastRow:
  if (current === lastRow) {
    // we append the cloned row to the parentNode of the
    // lastRow (which will be a <tbody>, not the <table>:
    lastRow.parentNode.appendChild(lastRow.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
```

```js
var table = document.getElementById('nodeTable');

table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var rows = this.rows,
    current = e.target,
    body = document.body,
    lastRow = rows[rows.length - 1];
  
  while (current.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'tr' && current !== body) {
    current = current.parentNode;
  }
  
  if (current === lastRow) {
    lastRow.parentNode.appendChild(lastRow.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  counter-reset: rowCount;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 3em;
  height: 2em;
}
td::before {
  content: counter(rowCount);
  counter-increment: rowCount;
}
```

```html
<table id="nodeTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[cloneNode() does not clone event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode#Notes). So you should move the callback function to a separate variable/named function and register it every time you clone it.

Alternatively use event bubbling